# Python regexp - remove punctuation but leave <unk> as is

Tags: python, regex

## Question

Please advise a way to remove punctuation, but not those in `<unk>` or `<UNK>`.

For instance, from:

`the asbestos fiber <unk> <unk| is < unusually <unk once it enters the <<unk>$% with`

generate:

`the asbestos fiber <unk> unk is unusually unk once it enters the unk with`

Tried below but not as expected.

```
text = "the asbestos fiber <unk> <unk| is < unusually <unk once it enters the <<unk>$% with "

replacement = " "
pattern: str = '(?<!<unk)[%s%s]+(?!unk>)' % (re.escape(string.punctuation), r"\s")

re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl=replacement, string=text, flags=re.IGNORECASE).lower().strip()
```

Result:
`the asbestos fiber <unk> unk| is unusually unk once it enters the <unk> with`

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: What does "in `<unk>`" mean? Between two `<unk>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex to search for matches and replace them with a space:

```
(?:(?!<unk>)[\W_](?<!<unk>))+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ya0VvR/2).

*Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?!<unk>)` - the nex char should not be a starting char of a `<unk>` char sequence
  - `[\W_]` - any non-alphanumeric char
  - `(?<!<unk>)` - the previously matched char (with `[\W_]`) cannot be a starting char of an `<unk>` char sequence
- `)+` - one or more times.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZPPRYI):

```py
import re
text = "the asbestos fiber <unk> <unk| is < unusually <unk once it enters the <<unk>$% with "
replacement = " "
pattern: str = r'(?:(?!<unk>)[\W_](?<!<unk>))+'
print( re.sub(pattern, replacement, text, flags=re.I) )
# => the asbestos fiber <unk> unk is unusually unk once it enters the <unk> with
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use a capture group to keep `<unk>`, match non word characters excluding whitespace chars, and replace the double whitespace chars (which can occur after the first substitution) with a single space.

```
(?i)(?<!\S)(<unk>)(?!\S)|[^\w\s]+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?i)` inline modifier for case insensitive
- `(?<!\S)(<unk>)(?!\S)` Capture `<unk>` between whitespace boundaries in **group 1** to keep in the replacement.
- `|` Or
- `[^\w\s]+` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except a word or whitespace char to be deleted

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CtPyZP/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/dmiEB4)

```
import re

text = "the asbestos fiber <unk> <unk| is < unusually <unk once it enters the <<unk>$% with "
pattern = r"(?i)(?<!\S)(<unk>)(?!\S)|[^\w\s]+"

print(re.sub(r"\s{2,}", ' ', re.sub(pattern, r"\1", text)).lower().strip())
```

Output

```
the asbestos fiber <unk> unk is  unusually unk once it enters the unk with
```